# display different sprites randomly in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random, cocos2d-iphone

am trying to jump the different sprite at randomly .

am having 5 disffrent sprites have to display randomly . one sprite to be displayed

am tryed below code but its crashed :- ***warning: 'CCSprite' may not respond to '+spriteWithName:'***

```
NSString *Sprit;

    NSInteger rnd = arc4random() % 6;

    if (rnd == 1) {
        Sprit = @"Target.png";
    } else if (rnd == 2) {
        Sprit = @"3.png";
    }else if (rnd == 3) {
        Sprit = @"5.png";
    } else if (rnd == 4) {
        Sprit = @"8.png";
    } else if (rnd == 5) {
        Sprit = @"10.png";
    }  else {
        Sprit = @"13.png";
    }

    CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithName:Sprit];

target.position = ccp(winSize.height + (target.contentSize.height/4), actualX);
    [self addChild:target ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to use:

```
CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:Sprit];
```

instead? Note that it's spriteWith***File***

There is some documentation for the CCSprite class here:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d4/de7/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_sprite.html